# On Click Listener to Specific lists in ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview

This is my xml code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Clicking"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ClickingOne"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImageTwo"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFullNameTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I want to set an on click listener to android:id="@+id/ClickingOne" and android:id="@+id/Clicking" not the entire listView adapter. I want it so the There are two on click listener on the two different lists labeled as Clicking and ClickingOne.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it inside the onBindView or ViewHolder class.
Try something like

```
Clicking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
// do your thing here
})
```

And set the `android:clickable` for linearlayout to `true` and `false` to all children view inside it.
Do the same to ClickingOne.

Comment: Clicking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
// do your thing here
            })
            ClickingOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
// do your thing here
            })

Comment: What is the error? Can you add the adapter class so we can know how you implement it.

Comment: Do i put it in the adapter class?

Comment: Yeah, inside the adapter, put it in ViewHolder class or bindView method

Comment: What do you mean by text comes up red?